# ListView in Windows Phone 8 apps

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a Windows Runtime application on the Windows 8 Store and would like to use some similar features in my new (and first) Windows Phone 8 phone app.

Is there a `ListView` native to Windows Phone 8? Or can we use a `ListView` in a Windows Phone 8 app? I could not find one in the Toolbox.

If there is no `ListView`, is it possible to have some kind of a list, that allows for Horizontal orientation (meaning, all list items are presented horizontally - not Top-Down)?

And what about a FlipView control? Can we use the Windows 8 Metro FlipView control in a Windows Phone app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can review this link for difference in Xaml Controls between Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8:

[XAML controls comparison between Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735581%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

you will find that there is no ListView Or FlipView in Windows Phone 8 . may be you can use insteas LongListSelector

Comment: Thank you very much @Ahmed, this link is helpful. I knew about the LongListSelector but I didn't think it could be used in my particular scenario because I didn't see any relevant layout options that were like the ListView. But I'm still learning so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: i suggest for you to change your senario for Windows Phone 8 . Windows Phone 8 apps and Windows 8 can share alot of code but when it comes to interface they are different from many views ( Namespace of controls , Navigation controls and User Experience). so in Windows Phone 8 it is common to user scrool veritcally and if you want horizontal motion it is better to use Panorama or Pivot .

Comment: Thank you @Ahmed. I will rethink my scenario.

Comment: That's a useful link.  Would this answer need to be revised for Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: Yes. Windows Phone 8.1 has ListView control.